# Gson incorrectly parses true as false

Tags: android, gson

I am using Retrofit+Gson+RxJava2CallAdapter to interact with my backend.
Here is data class that represents server response

```kotlin
data class CheckResponse(
    val success: Boolean,
    val redirect: String
)
```

With OkHttp Is see that received response is `{"success":true,"redirect":null}`
However, it is getting parsed as `CheckResponse(success=false, redirect=null)`
Somehow my `true` in JSON became `false` in parsed object.

More detailed information can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Mexator/7ceadb5393377e2115447c66e24ed281)

This problem appears when I upload signed application bundle to Google Play. In debug mode everything works properly.

Comment: could you please include enough information here for us to recreate the prroblem ? could you include the code you use to parse your responses and any other relevant info here

Comment: Your application is most-likely got obfuscated for the release mode using Proguard, thus the `success` field got renamed to whatever else. Then it is clearly not a Gson bug, and requires either adding an explicit `@SerializedName("success")` annotation for the `success` field so that Proguard would not affect it, or tell Proguard ignore your DTO classes (by name, etc).

Comment: Yeah, thank you. Adding Proguard rules, as [official example](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg) suggests helped me.

Comment: I think @fluffy suggestion to user `SerializedName` is better than removing models from proguard

Comment: Seems an obfuscation issue. Try adding `@Keep` on top of your data class